# Selenium Enable popup in chrome

Tags: node.js, selenium, automation

The web site i am navigating using selenium will open a popup, that's why i added this options to chrome.

```js
var chromeOptions  = new chrome.Options();
chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.setUserPreferences({'profile.default_content_settings.images':'2'});
chromeOptions.setUserPreferences({'profile.default_content_settings.popups':'2'});
```

After the click, a new window is opened, this window contained the popup that I need to treat, so i switched to this window and noticed that the popup is not hundled.

this is what driver.getPageSource() on this new window returned:

```html
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _AdfWindowOpenError='A popup window blocker has been detected in your browser. Popup blockers interfere with the operation of this application. Please disable your popup blocker or allow popups from this site.';</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fscmUI/adf/jsLibs/Locale2lzbpv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fscmUI/adf/jsLibs/Common2lzbpv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onkeydown=_noReload;
        var _blockReload=1;
        function _fixDialogTitle(){ 
            window.document.title=window.document.getElementById('_adfvdlg').contentWindow.document.title};</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<frameset title="Content" rows="100%,*" 
    onload="_fixDialogTitle();
        _sizeWin(window.document.getElementById('_adfvdlg').contentWindow,0,30,{W:700,H:400})" 
    onunload="try {
        var pw = top.opener; 
        if (!pw) return; 
        var p = (pw['AdfPage'] ? pw.AdfPage.PAGE : null); 
        var ds = (pw['AdfDhtmlRichDialogService'] ? pw.AdfDhtmlRichDialogService.getInstance() : null);
        if (ds &amp;&amp; p) p.scheduleTimer(ds, ds.checkForWindowCanceled, '1577377052947', 1, {'isSynchronized':true});
    }
    catch (e){};">
    <frame id="_adfvdlg" name="_adfvdlg" title="Content" frameborder="0" noresize="" src="/fscmUI/faces/adf.dialog-request?_adf.ctrlstate=73950a4hf_129&amp;_afrLoop=4736492517208121&amp;_rtrnId=1577377052947" longdesc="#">
    <noframes>Your browser does not support frames. Frames support is required for this functionality</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe explain a bit more about the problem here...does the frame load?  Do you see any prompts in the browser about allowing a pop-up?   The window has opened since you are getting the page source.  It's loading another page into a frameset in that window... so to interact with that you'd also want to switch the driver to the frame you want in the frameset... that is IF the browser has loaded that frame.  It's possible that it won't because that frame is trying to pop-up another window without user action.

Comment: Thank you for your response, as you sad,  it was a question of frame, i had to switch to the frame.